# How Could I Make A Function For The Start Game Button To Disable The Start Screen And Load My Main Game?

Tags: python, pygame

so I have a game intro here and I was wonder how can I make it so when my ***mouse clicks on the start game button to disable the the game_intro? its currently not doing anything and [vid](https://gyazo.com/b927d1aa3be6a5d4c81d6d33cb8f63c2)

like how could I make a function for start button when I click it, it should remove the game_intro or disable it and load my main game

this is my game intro right now

```
#---------------------------------------------------


def button(msg,x,y,w,h,ic,ac):
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

    if x+w > mouse[0] > x and y+h > mouse[1] > y:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, ac,(x,y,w,h))
    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, ic,(x,y,w,h))

        if clikc[0] == 1 and action != None:
            action()
        else:
            pygame.draw.rect(window,ic,(x,y,w,h))


    smallText = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf",20)
    textSurf, textRect = text_objects(msg, smallText)
    textRect.center = ( (x+(w/2)), (y+(h/2)) )
    gameDisplay.blit(textSurf, textRect)
#------------------------------------------------------


def text_objects(text, font):
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, black)
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()

def game_intro():
    red = (200,0,0)
    green = (0,200,0)
    bright_red = (255,0,0)
    bright_green = (0,255,0)

    intro = True
    while intro:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            #print(event)
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        window.fill((255,255,255))
        largeText = pygame.font.Font('BLOODY.ttf',115)
        TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("Stolen Hearts!", largeText)
        TextRect.center = ((800/2), (800/2))
        window.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

# make the square brighter if collideded with the buttons
        mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        if 150+120 > mouse[0] > 150 and 450+50 > mouse[1] > 450:
            pygame.draw.rect(window, bright_green,(150,450,120,50))
        else:
            pygame.draw.rect(window, green,(150,450,120,50))
        if 550+110 > mouse[0] > 550 and 450+50 > mouse[1] > 450:
            pygame.draw.rect(window, bright_red,(550,450,110,50))
        else:
            pygame.draw.rect(window, red,(550,450,110,50))
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------

        smallText = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf",20)
        textSurf, textRect = text_objects("Start Game", smallText)
        textRect.center = ( (150+(120/2)), (450+(50/2)) )
        window.blit(textSurf, textRect)


        smallText = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf",20)
        textSurf, textRect = text_objects("Quit Game", smallText)
        textRect.center = ( (150+(910/2)), (450+(50/2)) )
        window.blit(textSurf, textRect)


        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(15)



#----------------------------------------------------------
```

my full code script

Comment: inside main loop use variables like `start_screen = True/False` `main_game = True/False` to control which part to display, And use button to change values in `start_screen` and `main_game`

Comment: in button you have `action()` - it should be function which runs main game code.

Comment: BTW: you could define fonts only once - at start. If text doesn't change then you could define `textSurf, textRect` for every text only once  - at start - but with different names `textSurf_start_game, textRect_start_game`

Comment: I don't understand - you have function `button()` but you don't use it - why? `button()` checks if you clicked mouse and runs `action()` - and in function `action()` you should run main game.

Comment: I am confused how can I control it for the start game button I dont have a main_game how could I define my main_game? I tried to give it for my main code but it makes my screen black

Comment: forget `start_screen` and `main_game` - you have `button()` and you should use it.

Comment: I see your full code and: you should add link without "raw" but first you should put code again and set "Language: Python" - this way code would be highlighted and more readable.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/hjSiJBrE here sorry I didnt know what changing it to python language on pastebin was

Comment: put this link in question, not in comment. Other people will read question and see old link - it is useless.

Comment: yah also I dont really know how to use that button it really does nothing even when I call it I was watching a tutorial on how to make  a start screen but I am stuck with how I could make my start button work even when  I make a `def main_loop` function for my main loop  and call it below it will just show black screen nothing will load

Comment: I saw this `button` before and it seems you have mistakes in code. You forgot `action` in `def button(msg, x, y, w, h, ic, ac, action):`, You forgot `click = ...`

Comment: [image](https://gyazo.com/1b0071bca37383493f7ced5f9bca2923) it still really does nothing

Comment: because you have many other mistakes. And you have to use this `button()` in `game_intro()`

Comment: ok so this is what I did `button("Start Game",150,450,100,50,green,bright_green,game_loop)` currently how I dont have a game_loop can you help me make a `def game_loop` for my main loop because everytime I do it nothing shows up it just shows black

Comment: ok nvm I fixed that issue but I am getting an error  ` File "C:\Users\Habib\Desktop\PYTHONGGAME\py.py", line 2084, in game_loop
    window.blit(text,textRect)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'text' referenced before assignment` when I click my button to load my game_loop  [image](https://gyazo.com/0d645d49433c8816a8479cbd07dfd837)

Comment: at the end of full code you have `while runninggame:`, etc. Put it in `game_loop`

Comment: why do you use `blit(text, ...)` if you don't have `text` ? It makes no sense.

Comment: thats for the coins

Comment: nvm it works thank you for helping me!

Comment: I just removed that part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove mistakes in `button()` and you have to use `button()` in `game_intro()`

There is too many to explain so I only show minimal working code.

Buttons works but they still are not ideal. It will have problem if new scene will have buttons in the same place - it will click it automatically - but it would need totally different code. More on [GitHub](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/pygame/button-using-function/function-from-some-tutorial)

```
import pygame

# --- constants --- (UPPER_CASE_NAMES)

RED = (200, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 200, 0)

BRIGHT_RED = (255, 0, 0)
BRIGHT_GREEN = (0, 255, 0)

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)

# --- all classes --- (CamelCaseNames)

class Player:
    pass
    # ... code ...

class Platform:
    pass
    # ... code ...

# etc.

# --- all functions --- (lower_case_names)

def text_objects(text, font):
    image = font.render(text, True, BLACK)
    rect  = image.get_rect()
    return image, rect

def button(window, msg, x, y, w, h, ic, ac, action=None):

    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

    if x+w > mouse[0] > x and y+h > mouse[1] > y:
        pygame.draw.rect(window, ac,(x,y,w,h))
        if click[0] == 1 and action != None:
            action()
    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(window, ic,(x,y,w,h))

    image = small_font.render(msg, True, BLACK)
    rect = image.get_rect()
    rect.center = (x+(w/2), y+(h/2))

    window.blit(image, rect)

def game_intro():

    running = True

    while running:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        window.fill((255,255,255))

        image, rect = text_objects("Stolen Hearts!", large_font)
        rect.center = (400, 400)
        window.blit(image, rect)

        button(window, "Start Game", 150, 450, 120, 50, GREEN, BRIGHT_GREEN, main_game)
        button(window, "Quit Game",  350, 450, 120, 50, RED, BRIGHT_RED, quit_game)

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(15)

def main_game():

    running = True

    while running:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        window.fill((255,255,255))

        image, rect = text_objects("Main Game", large_font)
        rect.center = (400, 400)
        window.blit(image, rect)

        button(window, "Intro",     550, 450, 120, 50, GREEN, BRIGHT_GREEN, game_intro)
        button(window, "Quit Game", 350, 450, 120, 50, RED, BRIGHT_RED, quit_game)

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(15)

def quit_game():
    print("You quit game")
    pygame.quit()
    quit()

# --- main ---

pygame.init()

window = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 800))

# it has to be after `pygame.init()`    
#small_font = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf", 20)
#large_font = pygame.font.Font('BLOODY.ttf', 115)
small_font = pygame.font.Font(None, 20)
large_font = pygame.font.Font(None, 115)

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

game_intro()
```

---

BTW: I also organize code in different way

- all constants values in one place directly after `imports` and they use `UPPER_CASE_NAMES` (PEP8) and
- all classes in one place - directly after constants and before `pygame.init()` - and they use `CamelCaseNames` (PEP8)
- all functions in one place - after classes and before `pygame.init()` - and they use`lower_case_names` (PEP8)

See: [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)